# how to stop bot to not move forward unless entity is resolves

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

```
    var intent = args.intent;
    var number = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'builtin.numer');
```

when i use findentity it move forward if the answer is correct or not how can i use entity resolve on that which are not builtin entites

```
    var location1 = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Location');
    var time = builder.EntityRecognizer.resolveTime(intent.entities);
```

when i use resolve time it ask againand again unless entity is resolve;

```
    var alarm = session.dialogData.alarm = {
      number: number ? number.entity : null,
      timestamp: time ? time.getTime() : null,
      location1: location1? location1.entity :null
    };
    /*  if (!number & !location1 time)
     {} */


    // Prompt for number
    if (!alarm.number) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'how many people you are');
    } else {
        next();
    }
},
function (session, results, next) {
    var alarm = session.dialogData.alarm;

    if (results.response) {
        alarm.number = results.response;
    }
```

Comment: Closing GH issue [#2594](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2594). Please only post SDK-related bugs, issues or suggestions on GitHub and place general how-to questions here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've already answered this question on StackOverflow: "*[Botframework Prompt dialogs until user finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188558/botframework-prompt-dialogs-until-user-finishes/43193228#43193228)*".

You'll need to create a mini-dialog, that will have at least two waterfall steps. Your first step will take any `args` and check/set them as the potential value your chatbot is waiting for. It'll prompt the user to verify that these are the correct values. If no `args` were passed in, or the data was not valid, the user will be prompted to supply the value the chatbot is waiting for.

The second step will take the user's response to the first step and either set the value into a `session` data object (like `session.userData` or `session.conversationData`) or restart the dialog using **[session.replaceDialog()](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#replacedialog)** or [**session.beginDialog()**](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#begindialog).

In your main dialog you'll modify the step where you employ your `EntityRecognizers` to include an if-statement that begins your mini-dialog. To trigger the if-statement, you could use the same design as shown in this [GitHub example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/basics-naturalLanguage/app.js#L32) or in your code. This code might look like below:

```
var location1 = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(intent.entities, 'Location');

session.userData.location1 = location1 ? location1.entity : null;

if(!session.userData.location1) {
    session.beginDialog('<get-location-dialog>');
}
```

Comment: we could not do it in prompt and make check whether the entity is solved or not something like that given below

Comment: The Prompts will check if the value or value type matches the value asked for. For example, if using `builder.Prompts.number()`, the chatbot uses a regex pattern to match what was provided by the user. Likewise for `.choices()` it'll examine the user's response to see that it matches the options provided. However, for `.text()` it will not do these things, and also not check against any values you're expecting in your next waterfall step.